# Programming Language in Cucumber

Tags: cucumber

I just finished reading about Cucumber from various sources. One stated that Cucumber could be used in many programming languages, including Ruby, Java, and JavaScript.

Besides the above languages, what other programming language can be used in Cucumber?

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber is available for most mainstream programming languages, you can see a complete list and how they are supported by Cucumber at :

https://cucumber.io/docs/installation/

It also shows you how to install Cucumber for your preferred language.